# Python 3.8.2 | VkBotLongPoll 5.103 как достать id пользователя, чтобы записать в базу данных?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Делаю чат-бота вк. Когда пользователь пишет в беседу впервые, бот должен заносить его id в БД. Изначально делал бота на VkLongPoll, но пришлось перейти на VkBotLongPoll, т.к. он тот не отвечал в беседы, в которые его добавляли.
Не пойму как достать id пользователя из его сообщения.

```
vk_session = VkApi(token="Тут Токен")
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "Тут id")
vk = vk_session.get_api()

conn = sqlite3.connect("db.db")
c = conn.cursor()

session = requests.Session()

def check_if_exists(user_id):
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = %d" % user_id)
    result = c.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        return False
    return True

def register_new_user(user_id):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO users(user_id, state) VALUES (%d, '')" % user_id)
    conn.commit()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO user_info(user_id, user_wish) VALUES (%d, 0)" % user_id)
    conn.commit()

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and "key" in event.message.text.lower():    #  "key" in event.message.text.lower() для того, чтобы бот отзывался только если в сообщение есть ключевое слово

        if not check_if_exists(event.user_id):
                register_new_user(event.user_id)        

        if "хай" in event.message.text.lower():
            vk.messages.send(
                random_id=random.randint(1, 10000),
                chat_id=event.chat_id,
                message="Хаю-хай")
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\Python\projects\vkbot2.py", line 34, in 
    if not check_if_exists(event.user_id):
AttributeError: 'VkBotMessageEvent' object has no attribute 'user_id'

Как достать id отдельного пользователя беседы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для `Long Poll v5.103`:

```py
user_id = event.obj['message']['from_id']
```

---

***P. S.:***

- `random_id` можно получить с помощью функции `get_random_id` из
  модуля `vk_api.utils`
- Для отправки сообщений можно использовать универсальный идентификатор
  `peer_id` (чтобы отвечать и в ЛС и в беседу):

  ```py
  peer_id = event.obj['message']['peer_id']
  ```